# Auto-register All controllers in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In L4, is there an equivalent of L3's `Route::controller(Controller::detect());`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an equivalent, but it's easy to register your controllers:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

> The controller method accepts two arguments. The first is the base URI
>   the controller handles, while the second is the class name of the
>   controller.

Comment: hmmmm i wish taylor otwell soon create this functionality in future for Laravel 4.

Comment: I tried registering the `HomeController` that came with L4 using `Route::controller('home', 'HomeController');` but get an error `ResourceNotFoundException`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588409/controller-route-not-found-in-laravel-4

Comment: this method does not exist in `laravel-4`

Answer (score 2):

This will most likely not be implemented in laravel 4, the reason is that the autoload all contollers is broken by design. In laravel, the order that controllers are defined matters, meaning autoloading all controllers could break your app.