# Controller Route not found in Laravel 4

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-4

I am in the process of migrating from L3 to L4. When registering the `HomeController` controller that came with the default L4 installation, trying to go to the page `www.domain.com/home` gives me a `ResourceNotFound` exception. I did a `composer dumpautoload` but that did not help.

Did I miss out an additional step?

**routes.php**

```
Route::controller('home', 'HomeController');
```

**controllers/HomeController.php**

```
<?php

class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function showWelcome()
    {
        return View::make('hello');
    }

}
```

**Error Stacktrace**

```
NotFoundHttpException:
in /var/www/l4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php line 1338
at Router->handleRoutingException(object(ResourceNotFoundException)) in /var/www/l4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php line 992
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in /var/www/l4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php line 956
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in /var/www/l4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php line 463
at Application->dispatch(object(Request)) in /var/www/l4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php line 448
at Application->run() in /var/www/l4/public/index.php line 51
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers):

> Next, just add methods to your controller, prefixed with the HTTP verb
>   they respond to

So:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex() 
    {
        // Would response to /user and /user/index
    }
}
```

So, in your case simply renaming `showWelcome()` to `getWelcome()` should suffice.

Comment: I notice that `getWelcome()` and `get_welcome()` works but not `getwelcome()`. `action_welcome()` no longer works?

Comment: Indeed. I guess it is generally a good practice to camel case your method names anyway.

Comment: It's rare that an action would be called for multiple HTTP request types, but it should be possible with `Route::any('foo', 'MyController@action')`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your route to this:

```
Route::resource('home', 'HomeController');
```

UPDATE: My bad, I thought you wanted a resourceful controller, as described here: http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

For "normal" RESTful controllers juco's answer seems right.

If you want basic controllers, you can use this to correspond to your controller method:

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
```